# Creating a summary Google Sheet List from the same cells in multiple Google Sheet files

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to capture the data from the same two cells (A8 and D8) in multiple files within a folder. I want to then create a summary list of these two cells for reference. I have tried various iterations of this after watching several videos. Just wondering if anyone might have ideas on this forum, since for my past apps scripts, I referenced several of the questions/answers here. Thank you!

I have included while statements to iterate through the folder and also did two different functions (one to pull the data and one to create the list), but it still doesn't work.

Here is what I have in one combined script (which seems to get me to the closest to success):

\\
function CreateSunscreenList() {

```
const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("Actual Folder ID Here");  
var files = folder.getFiles();

while(files.hasNext()){  
 var file = files.next();  
 var worksheets = SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId());  
 var sheets = worksheets.getSheets()[0];  
 var data1 = sheets.getRange("A8").getValues();  
 var data2 = sheets.getRange("D8").getValues();  

var combinedData = [data1, data2];  
console.log(data1,data2)  

var list = combinedData.concat(combinedData);
```

}

```
var summary = 
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sunscreen 
List");  

summary.getRange(5,1,combinedData.length,2).setValues(list);
```

}
\
The error I receive is:

Exception: The number of rows in the data does not match the number of rows in the range. The data has 4 but the range has 2.

My data is being pulled as follows, so I feel I need to maybe adjust this somehow?

[ [ 'Child 1' ] ] [ [ 'Equate SPF 50' ] ]

[ [ 'Child 2' ] ] [ [ 'Banana Boat SPF 40' ] ]

Answer (score 0):

```
function myfunk() {
  const ts = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ts.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  sh.getRange("A1:D1").setValues([["Name","ID","SheetName","A5","H5"]]);
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("foid");
  const files = folder.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS);
  let vs = [];
  while(files.hasNext()) {
    let file = files.next();
    let ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId());
    let s = ss.getSheets()[0];
    vs.push([ss.getName(),file.getId(),s.getName(),s.getRange("A5").getValue(),s.getRange("H5").getValue()]);
  }
  sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow() + 1, 1, vs.length,vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I was able to get it working now! I really appreciate your help! Next, I am going to try to include an if statement to leave the second column blank if the form isn't approved (signature line is at A13).